# python- Unable to read table in salesforce using Bulk Api with "pk_chunking" enabled to create multiple batches to retrieve the data faster

Tags: python, salesforce, heroku-api

while trying to read the accounts table in salesforce by enabling the pk_chunking = True , getting an error as

> salesforce_bulk.salesforce_bulk.BulkBatchFailed: Batch 7511M00000KiqGsQAJ of job None failed: None

I looked at the salesforce monitoring and there are 11 batches created by the `pk_chunking` and all the batches except the above case have the results and their requests look like

```sql
select Id from Account where Id >='' and Id<'' "
```

Here is the code I wrote:

```
table_names = ['Account','table1']
bulk = connect_sfdc_bulk('prod')
for x in table_names:
    job = bulk.create_query_job(x, contentType='CSV', pk_chunking=True)
    batch = bulk.query(job, "select Id from %s" % x)
    print(bulk.get_batch_list(job))
    print('batch status: ' , bulk.is_batch_done)
    while not bulk.is_batch_done(batch):
        time.sleep(6)
    for result in bulk.get_all_results_for_query_batch(batch):
        result = unicodecsv.DictReader(result, encoding='utf-8')
    # print(result)
    bulk.close_job(job)
```

Please recommend how can I fix this error and read the large tables from salesforce with batches in parallel?

Comment: Do you see a concrete error associated with the failed job in Salesforce Setup? What does its request look like? Is the Python library you are using here `salesforce_bulk`?

Comment: @DavidReed Yes, I'm using the python library "salesforce_bulk".

Here is the error message that I have got using the API:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/sfdc_test.py", line 51, in <module>
    while not bulk.is_batch_done(batch):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/salesforce_bulk/salesforce_bulk.py", line 428, in is_batch_done
    raise BulkBatchFailed(job_id, batch_id, status.get('stateMessage'), batch_state)
salesforce_bulk.salesforce_bulk.BulkBatchFailed: Batch 7511M00000KiuKjQAJ of job None failed: None

Comment: @DavidReed Details from the job monitoring in Salesforce:

Concurrency_mode - Parallel,Api Version - 40.0, Records processed - 10000. 
Batches:
 Batch id: 7511M00000KiuKjQAJ—> records processed: 0 —> Status: Not Processed —> Request : “select Id from Account"
 batch Id: 7511M00000kiuko.. —> records processed: 10000—> Status: Completed —> Request : “select Id from Account where Id >= ‘ ’ and Id < ‘ ’ ”

Comment: @Kumar Did you find any solution to this issue?
I am also facing the same issue while doing pk_chunking

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same error and how i resolved is by adding "job" parameter to get_all_results_for_query_batch(batch,**Job**)

so code will be like this

```
table_names = ['Account','table1']
bulk = connect_sfdc_bulk('prod')
for x in table_names:
    job = bulk.create_query_job(x, contentType='CSV', pk_chunking=True)
    batch = bulk.query(job, "select Id from %s" % x)
    print(bulk.get_batch_list(job))
    print('batch status: ' , bulk.is_batch_done)
    while not bulk.is_batch_done(batch):
        time.sleep(6)
    for result in bulk.get_all_results_for_query_batch(batch,job):
        result = unicodecsv.DictReader(result, encoding='utf-8')
    # print(result)
    bulk.close_job(job)
```